# How can use zoom instead responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I saw a site that added a style to the root tag of this website that changed the zoom value according to the device resolution and prevented the layout from being messed up, even with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> keys.

Can anyone tell me how do they do this?

website :

https://pg-stage.rpd.cloud/blast/?partnerId=4&currency=USD&culture=en&gameTypeId=182&theme=Winter&mode=fun&gameId=32&currencySymbol=%24

I tried to do it in different ways, but I couldn't.

Comment: Note that the duplicate specifically mentions 'mobile web page' but it works for other clients too.

Comment: Zooming can be prevented using the `meta` `viewport` HTML tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimal-ui,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,viewport-fit=auto,user-scalable=no">
```

Make sure to set `maximum-scale=1` and `user-scalable=no`

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag